# How to select multiple columns but only group by one?

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a problem with `group by`, I want to select multiple columns but group by only one column. The query below is what I tried, but it gave me an error.

```
SELECT Rls.RoleName,Pro.[FirstName],Pro.[LastName],Count(UR.[RoleId]) as [Count]
from [b.website-sitecore-core].[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] UR
inner join [b.website-professional-au].[dbo].[Profile]  Pro
on UR.UserId = Pro.Id
inner join [b.website-sitecore-core].[dbo].[aspnet_Roles] Rls
on Rls.RoleId = UR.RoleId
inner join [b.website-professional-au].[dbo].[Gender] Gn
on gn.Id = pro.GenderId
GROUP BY Rls.RoleName;
```

Answer (score 24):

In SQL Server you can only select columns that are part of the `GROUP BY` clause, or aggregate functions on any of the other columns. [I've blogged about this in detail here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/). So you have two options:

1. Add the additional columns to the `GROUP BY` clause:

   ```
   GROUP BY Rls.RoleName, Pro.[FirstName], Pro.[LastName]
   ```
2. Add some aggregate function on the relevant columns:

   ```
   SELECT Rls.RoleName, MAX(Pro.[FirstName]), MAX(Pro.[LastName])
   ```

The second solution is mostly a workaround and an indication that you should fix something more general with your query.

Comment: *"In SQL Server you can only select columns that are part of the GROUP BY clause, or aggregate functions on any of the other columns..."* is something what I was looking for.. Thnx

Comment: NOTE: these two options can provide absolutely WRONG results! `GROUP BY A,B,C` can be totally different than what you want to get in comparison with `GROUP BY A`. and also, usually we can't use some aggregate function to get related column value. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626810/2803565) as a solution

Comment: I know that the two queries will give exactly same results in my case (always). But I want to know which is more efficient. Lets say Rolename is pk in one of the table being joined (so indexed) and the other columns are type varchar. basically what does max do here ?

Comment: @MohitSingh: I recommend asking a new question

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This answer is intended as a supplement to [@Lukas Eder's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71889/52150)*

If there are multiple values present for the fields `SELECT`ed but a field you wish to `GROUP BY`, you could instead grab the top matching line, rather than waiting for an aggregation (`MAX`) to return.

```
SELECT i.RoleName, i.*
FROM Rls JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 1 R.Rolename, Pro.FirstName, Pro.LastName FROM Rls as R JOIN Pro ON ... ) as i
     ON i.Rolename=Rls.RoleName
```

if you want ALL values to return in those other columns, but want to collapse it to a single entry see: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I wanted to group by something from a transactional table where the timestamp was the latest entry. So for example an audit table that had a username, someUniqueId and a timestamp.

So I could get the max timestamp of when all the objects were last updated via:

```
  SELECT max(timeStamp) AS timeStamp, someUniqueId 
  FROM tableName
  GROUP BY someUniqueId
```

But then I couldn't pull out any other columns, ie, the username... I managed to solve this by selecting from the main table and using the above result set in an inner join like so:

```
  SELECT a.someUniqueId, a.timeStamp, a.username
  FROM tableName a
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(timeStamp) AS timeStamp, someUniqueId 
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY someUniqueId 
  ) b ON a.someUniqueId = b.someUniqueId AND a.timeStamp = b.timeStamp
```